# XSL-FO Stylesheets & Xalan XSLTransformation Engine

Tags: xml, pdf, xslt, stylesheet, xsl-fo

I'm using Arbortext Publisher (not to be confused with Arbortext Editor). My Google research tells me that the Arbortext Publisher application utilizes a Xalan XSL Transformation Engine (as opposed to Saxon) to convert XML to a PDF. However, the XSL-FO stylesheets I need to use don't seem to be recognizable by the Xalan Engine. Is it possible to somehow edit the XSL-FO stylesheets so that they may be compatible with the Xalan Engine? Any opinion will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Xylan? Perhaps Xalan?

Comment: You are correct.  It is correctly spelled "XALAN"  Sorry for my mistake.  The question in a nutshell, is Xalan designed to support XSL-FO stylesheets?

Comment: Xalan or any other XSL transformer has nothing to do with XSL FO other than they create it given the proper XML and XSL.  Many 1000s of people use Xalan and create XSL FO so that is not the issue. And note an XSLT processor like Xalan does not convert XML to a PDF, it converts XML to XSL FO but not PDF. An XSL FO Engine converts XSL FO to PDF.